# DIY exterior door casing

Tags: doors, woodworking, door-frame

I have a couple of solid wood door slabs and wanted to install them into a casing that is weatherstrip friendly. Split door jamb casings don't seem to be compatible with this design, so I figured I'd make my own casings.  Based on the measurements of my existing exterior doors, it looks like it has a 1x5 for frame and 1x3 for the jamb.  Has anyone done this themselves and is it as straightforward to construct as I'm imagining (plus the latch hole and mortising the hinge of course)?

Comment: You seem to be misusing the word "casing", which is the trim that laps from the wall to the jamb edge. "Frame" and "jamb" are the same thing. Also, your question isn't clear. Please edit to ask something more specific than "is this straightforward". A photo or sketch would help, too.

Comment: Seems like he is trying to make an exterior rabbeted door jamb out of 2 pieces per side. The 1X5 is the main part so to speak and the 1x3 is the door stop.

Answer (score 1):

The parts you are looking to cobble together, are already cut to the proper profile for an exterior door jamb on the shelves of the big box stores. The aluminum/wood sills are there too. The jamb is cut and ready to receive the typical weatherstripping used these days. here is a link to [the product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/EverMark-4-9-16-in-x-3-43-in-x-83-in-Primed-Frame-Set-477-542C/206088193?gclid=Cj0KEQiAwMLDBRDCh_r9sMvQ_88BEiQA6zuAQ0yl07hX68fKDpdawkxHq_V1aYIuATDfqvsPnUcQXQQaAiI88P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) at one store

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need and would cost almost the same anyway if I diyed it myself out of common board and weatherstripping.